# Пул соединений в java

Tags: java

Создаю пул соединений ,но mysql ругается на большое количество соединений,как я понимаю нужно закрыть соединение после его применения. Но разве пул соединений не для этого  создан,чтобы держать определенное количество соединений для быстрого доступа к ним из разных потоков? Подскажите пожалуйста,что я делаю не правильно,может я неправильно понимаю механизм работы пула соединений?

```
package ObjectPool;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PoolController {

ArrayList<Connection> conpool=new ArrayList<Connection>();
public int instancescount=0;
int maxinstancescount=100;
int ex=0;
public PoolController() throws ClassNotFoundException{
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
}
public Connection add(){
Connection con=null;
try {
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lesson","root");
    conpool.add(con);
    instancescount++;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return con;
}   
public Connection getconnection(){
Connection con=null;

if(conpool.size()>0){
 con=conpool.get(conpool.size()-1);
conpool.remove(conpool.size()-1);}else {
    if(instancescount<=maxinstancescount){
        ex++;
        //System.out.println(ex);
        con=add();
    }else{
    synchronized(conpool){  
while(conpool.size()<=0){

    try {conpool.wait();} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

}       

    }   
}

    return con; 
}

public void release(Connection con){
synchronized(conpool){
    conpool.add(con);
    conpool.notify();
}

}

 }
```

запускаю несколько потоков для одновременного обращения к базам данных:

```
     package DataSourcepackage;

   import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import ObjectPool.PoolController;

   public class Mainthread extends Thread {
   DataSource ds;
   int count;
   PoolController poolcontroller;
   public Mainthread(PoolController poolcontroller,int count) throws  IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException{
   this.poolcontroller=poolcontroller;
   this.count=count;
   start();
   }
   public void run(){
    Connection con=poolcontroller.getconnection();
    Statement stmt;
    try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query="INSERT INTO lesson.tele2   VALUES ('asd',"+count+",'eq')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        poolcontroller.release(con);

       } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }



        }

         }
```

а это главный класс с которого запускается 500 потоков:

```
package DataSourcepackage;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Calendar;

import ObjectPool.PoolController;

public class experiment {
public static void main(String [] args) throws SQLException,  ClassNotFoundException, IOException, PropertyVetoException{


    PoolController pool=new PoolController();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        new Mainthread(pool,i);
    }



     }
     }
```

выдает такое исключение:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data   source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many  connections"
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor33.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at ObjectPool.PoolController.add(PoolController.java:20)
at ObjectPool.PoolController.getconnection(PoolController.java:39)
at DataSourcepackage.Mainthread.run(Mainthread.java:21)
```

Comment: Значит у сервера имеется ограничение на количество одновременных подключений (по умолчанию 151). Либо снимите/ослабьте это ограничение, либо пересмотрите политику использования подключений. Обычно нет нужды в таком огромном количестве подключений, который ничего не делают. Подключения получают из пула на относительно короткий срок. Выполнил работу и как можно скорей вернул обратно в пул. Впрочем у вас там в пуле ограничитель примерно в 100 подключений. Сдаётся мне неправильно выполнили синхронизацию getconnection и release.

Comment: Тогда у меня вопрос вернуть в пул значить закрыть соединение или оставить соединение открытым и просто запихнуть обратно в arraylist? Мне кажется  или проблема не в количестве открытых соединений, а в количестве используемых соединений?

Comment: При возвращении в пул подключение остаётся открытым. Когда случилась ошибка, посмотрите размер массива, сравните его с параметром сервера max_connections. Подозреваю, что У Вас совершенно неправильно синхронизируются функции получения подключений. Поэтому получаете более 100, что и приводит в конце концов к исчерпанию ресурсов сервера.

Comment: Вы запустили 500 потоков. попали они в getconnection одновременно и у всех у них, грубо говоря, `instancescount == 0`. Вот и пытается прога открыть 500 подключений. На 151 возникает ошибка. Надо грамотнее расставлять синхронизацию. Если это не учебное задание, то использовать готовые пулы. Сейчас даже с jdbc драйвером поставляются.

Comment: да я это уже понял,спасибо за советы я просто сделал функцию getconnection() синхронизированным.